# Como definir uma chave fixa para um array?

Tags: php, array

Como posso definir uma chave para um array com vários valores?

O array lista todos os trackers (que no caso não tem uma chave definida);

```
$trackers = array(
    'udp://9.rarbg.to:2970',
    'udp://tracker.coppersurfer.tk:6969/announce',
    'udp://tracker.leechers-paradise.org:6969'
);

Resultado:
Array
    (
        [0] => udp://9.rarbg.to:2970
        [1] => udp://tracker.coppersurfer.tk:6969/announce
        [2] => udp://tracker.leechers-paradise.org:6969
    )

Resultado desejado:
Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [protocolo] => udp://9.rarbg.to:2970
            )
        [1] => Array
            (
                [protocolo] => udp://tracker.coppersurfer.tk:6969/announce
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [protocolo] => udp://tracker.leechers-paradise.org:6969
            )
    )
```

Obs.: antes de abrir a pergunta já revirei a internet e não achei nada que me ajuda-se.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basta iterar com um for ou foreach e adicionar a um novo array, é o básico do básico da linguagem:

```
$trackers = array(
    'udp://9.rarbg.to:2970',
    'udp://tracker.coppersurfer.tk:6969/announce',
    'udp://tracker.leechers-paradise.org:6969'
);

$newTracks = array();

foreach($tracks as $track) {
    $newTracks[] = array( 'protocolo' => $track );
}
```

Agora, algo um pouco mais "avançado", mas que é nativo da linguagem e bom aprender, são as referencias, no caso do PHP usamos o E comercial (`&`), assim não precisa criar um novo array, bastaria referenciar no valor DE CADA ITEM do foreach que irá atualizar o array atual, assim:

```
$trackers = array(
    'udp://9.rarbg.to:2970',
    'udp://tracker.coppersurfer.tk:6969/announce',
    'udp://tracker.leechers-paradise.org:6969'
);

foreach($tracks as &$track) {
    $track = array( 'protocolo' => $track );
}
```

Claro que se estiver usando um for normal nem precisará de referencias, pois você já terá o VALOR DO INDICE, assim:

```
$trackers = array(
    'udp://9.rarbg.to:2970',
    'udp://tracker.coppersurfer.tk:6969/announce',
    'udp://tracker.leechers-paradise.org:6969'
);

for ($i = 0; $i < count($tracks); ++$i) {
    $tracks[$i] = array( 'protocolo' => $track );
}
```

Dessa forma `$tracks[$i]` você pega o item do indice atual e assim `$tracks[$i] =` você atualiza ele

Comment: Uma coisa tão simples e eu procurando um método sofisticado para fazer isso, obrigado.